# Cannot make connection with pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

Trying to make a connection with pymongo and get this error:

```
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> con = Connection('localhost')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 236, in __init__
    max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 369, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: is mongod service run?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: In order for the pymongo library to run it must be able to connect to a mongodb server. So the question is, have you installed, and are you running, the mongodb service?

Comment: @FutoFarai check mongodb status via: /etc/init.d/mongod status. it must be start.

Comment: See the second step of the Prerequisites in the [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i am new at this

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` means you have no runned MongoDB instances.

First of, you should start it.
For example, for Ubuntu, it will be:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

But before, make sure you have mongodb installed.